# sort data by the largest and smallest variables in php?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I made the code to sort the data based on the smallest euclidean value and the biggest similarity, the data is sorted first based on the smallest euclidean value, if there is an ata that has the smallest euclidean value then the next is sorted by the biggest similarity, the code is as follows:

```
 $gg = [
      ["Kasus" => "K01", "Euclidean" => "4", "Similrity" => "0.6"],
      ["Kasus" => "K02", "Euclidean" => "3", "Similrity" => "0.7"],
      ["Kasus" => "K03", "Euclidean" => "1", "Similrity" => "0.8"],
      ["Kasus" => "K04", "Euclidean" => "1", "Similrity" => "0.9"],

    ];

function k_sort($k_a, $k_b) {
  return $k_a["Euclidean"] - $k_b["Euclidean"];
}

usort($gg, "k_sort");

foreach($gg as $ta) {
  echo "<br>";
    list($kasus, $euclidean, $similarity) = array_values($ta);
    echo $kasus."-".$euclidean."-".$similarity;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

the results of the output from the above code as follows:

[image]

but why does the output still sort by euclidean, what's wrong with my code?
The sequence should be K04, K03, K02, K01.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sorted by Euclidean distance but forgot to add the calculation for `Similrity`. So, your `usort()` would look like below with the [`spaceship operator`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) which is available since PHP7. If you want to do without it, you can just subtract  the values.

```
<?php

function k_sort($k_a, $k_b) {
  if($k_a["Euclidean"] - $k_b["Euclidean"] === 0) return $k_b['Similrity'] <=> $k_a['Similrity'];
  return $k_a["Euclidean"] <=> $k_b["Euclidean"];
}
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/dSvql

Answer (score 0):

hope it helpful...

```
$gg = [
      ["Kasus" => "K01", "Euclidean" => "4", "Similrity" => "0.6"],
      ["Kasus" => "K02", "Euclidean" => "3", "Similrity" => "0.7"],
      ["Kasus" => "K03", "Euclidean" => "1", "Similrity" => "0.8"],
      ["Kasus" => "K04", "Euclidean" => "1", "Similrity" => "0.9"],
];

function k_sort($k_a, $k_b) {
  if($k_a["Euclidean"] - $k_b["Euclidean"] === 0) return $k_b['Similrity'] <=> $k_a['Similrity'];
  return $k_a["Euclidean"] <=> $k_b["Euclidean"];
}

usort($gg, "k_sort");

foreach($gg as $ta) {
  echo "<br>";
    list($kasus, $euclidean, $similarity) = array_values($ta);
    echo $kasus."-".$euclidean."-".$similarity;
    echo "<br>";
}
```